# Uncaught TypeError: $(...)[0].reset is not a function

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, simple-form

**Goal**

After a form is successfully submitted, I would like to reset the form to being empty.

**Issue**

After submitting the form, I get the following error message in my console:`Uncaught TypeError: $(...)[0].reset is not a function`

When I console.log my content before the reset I get the form: `<div id=new-store-form>..</div>`

**What I've checked so far**

- In my application there are no id's, classes or anything else that are called "reset"
- Pure javascript `document.getElementById('new-store-form').reset();` gets me the same error message.

**Code**
views/stores/index.html.erb

```
<div class="show-panel-form"></div>
  <%= render "partials/show_panel_stores_overview"%>
</div>
```

views/partials/show_panel_stores_overview.html.erb

```
<%= link_to 'New store', new_store_path, remote: true %>
```

views/stores/new.js.erb

```
var form = $("<%= j(render 'form') %>");
var wrapper = $('<div>').attr('id', 'new-store-form').append(form);
$('.show-panel-form').html(wrapper);
```

views/stores/_form

```
<%= simple_form_for (Store.new) do |f|%>
<%= f.input :name %>
<%= f.button :submit%>
```

views/stores.create.js.erb

```
var form = $("<%= j(render 'form') %>");
var wrapper = $('<div>').attr('id', 'new-store-form').append(form);
$('.show-panel-form').html(wrapper);
console.log($("#new-store-form")[0])
$("#new-store-form")[0].reset(); // doesn't work
```

store controller

```
def new
    @store = current_user.store.build
    @store.age_tables.build
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to root_url, alert: 'Page not accessible' }
      format.js
    end
    authorize @store

  end

  def create
    @store = current_user.stores.create(store_params)
    authorize @store
    if @store.save
      respond_to do |format|
        format.js
      end
    else
      format.js
    end
  end
```

Comment: `<div>`s don't have a `reset()` method.

Comment: OK, unless I'm missing something, `var form = $("<%= j(render 'form') %>");` wouldn't create a form, as Ruby still needs to process this.

Comment: Hi VLAZ, thank you for the response. I render the new.js.erb view, which in turn renders the form by inserting the form partial into my div using the wrapper variable. Furthermore, it is saving the objects, so the create function seems to be working as well.

Comment: But you'll insert the string `"<%= j(render 'form') %>"` - this is not going to do anything, unless you have *something* that will pick it up and render it, it will not do anything.

Comment: Please correct me if I am misinterpreting your point. The form input is saving, so therefore the create action seems to work. The problem I am currently encountering is that the filled in form incl. green checks for valid input(?) is remaining in the screen instead of disappearing.

Comment: Point is that unless `"<%= j(render 'form') %>"` gets run through some interpreter, it will not generate a form. And you need to run `reset()` on a `<form>` element. It's been a while since I've done a little bit of Ruby on Rails, but I think `<%= j(render 'form') %>` is a template syntax that would be interpreted by RoR which is *on the server*. This, in turn, means that `$("<%= j(render 'form') %>")` does nothing client-side. Again, unless something intercepts and processes this as you add it via JS. Bottom line is that you need to `reset` the form, not the div. I don't know if you have one.

Comment: @VLAZ, the `render` call is procceded by rails (it's a .erb view, it's not just javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a selector that matches the form, not the wrapper `$('#new-store-form form').reset()` (note the extra "form" to select the actual form tag inside the div)